# Can't create a UIBarButtonItem TouchUpInside method?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, ibaction, touch-up-inside

With a normal button, I can create a Touch Up Inside method easily. With a `UIBarButtonItem`, the only `IBAction` available is `Selector`. Looking at previous Stack Overflow answers, I tried pressing a down button on the `UIBarButtonItem` to reveal a button, but there isn't any:

[image]

How can I create this `IBAction`? Thank you!

UPDATE: I tried creating an IBAction manual, and then ctrl dragging that IBAction to the Quit button in the file selector in the storyboard. But the method still isn't being triggered:

[image]

The line isn't being printed. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Use selector, drag that to the viewController object and choose the IBAction method

Comment: @MidhunMP I tried this, but there is no other IBAction available

Comment: I mean you need to define an IBAction method in your file and connect the selector of bar button to that method.

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes, I see. Sorry I am new to programming; could you provide the code needed to define this method?

Comment: If you are using swift, write like : @IBAction func toolBarItemSelected()
    {
        // Your code here
    }

Comment: Ok, but does the selector define the touchUpInside method? @MidhunMP

Comment: Selector works when you touch up inside on that bar button